# Issue with import in MEF MVVM Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mef

I am using MEF, MVVM and Silverlight4 and below is my code

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
 public partial class Main : UserControl
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Satisfy the MEF imports for the class.
            if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            {
                CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the datacontext to the viewmodel for this view
        /// </summary>
        [Import(ViewModelTypes.MainViewModel)]
        public object ViewModel
        {
            set
            {
                this.DataContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Windows.Input;
    [Export(ViewModelTypes.MainViewModel)]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainViewModel(IAuthenticationModel authModel, IprospectManagementModel managementModel)
        {
            this.authenticationModel = authModel;
            this.managementModel = managementModel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The authentication model.
        /// </summary>
        private IAuthenticationModel authenticationModel;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Iprospect management model.
        /// </summary>
        private IprospectManagementModel managementModel;

    }
```

Below is the error i am getting, Please do help me out trace the same.

The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) No valid exports were found that match the constraint '(exportDefinition.ContractName == "MainViewModel")', invalid exports may have been rejected.

Resulting in:

```
Cannot set import 'IProspectCommonApp.Client.Main.ViewModel (ContractName="MainViewModel")' on part 'IProspectCommonApp.Client.Main'.
Element: IProspectCommonApp.Client.Main.ViewModel (ContractName="MainViewModel") -->  IProspectCommonApp.Client.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably failing because there is no IAuthenticationModel and/or IprospectManagementModel exported.  The MainViewModel imports these via the ImportingConstructor, so it can't be created if they haven't been exported.

For more information on MEF debugging, see [How to Debug and Diagnose MEF Failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the link, one subject I was struggling with was how to debug a MEF app